# Drawing Circle in scheme language

Tags: scheme, geometry

I have recently used midpoint circle algorithm in scheme to draw a circle, however it can only draw a small circle that radius not bigger than 10, when the radius increase, it become a octagon. Can anyone tell me how to correct my code?

```
(define (Circle x0 y0 r)
  (let ((x 0) (y r) (dp (- 1 r)))
   (CircleGo dp x0 x y0 y)))

(define (CircleGo dp x0 x y0 y)
  (let ((x1 (+ x 1))(y1 (- y 1)))
    (let ( (dp1 (+ (* 2 x1) 3)) (dp2 (+ (- (* 2 x1) (* 2 y1)) 5)))
        (if (<= x y)
              (if (< dp 0)
              (append (list (+ x0 x)(+ y0 y)
                        (- x0 x) (+ y0 y)
                         (+ x0 x) (- y0 y)
                             (- x0 x) (- y0 y)
                                (+ x0 y) (+ y0 x)
                                     (- x0 y) (+ y0 x)
                                        (+ x0 y) (- y0 x)
                                          (- x0 y) (- y0 x))
                (CircleGo dp1 x0 x1 y0 y))
              (append (list (+ x0 x) (+ y0 y)
                         (- x0 x) (+ y0 y)
                           (+ x0 x) (- y0 y)
                             (- x0 x) (- y0 y)
                               (+ x0 y) (+ y0 x)
                                 (- x0 y) (+ y0 x)
                                   (+ x0 y) (- y0 x)
                                    (- x0 y) (- y0 x))
                (CircleGo dp2 x0 x1 y0 y1)))    
          (list )))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has a lot more to do with math than with programming. It sounds like you need a function that accepts a center, a radius, and an angle in radians and returns the x and y coordinates of the specified point. Sine and Cosine are your friends here. Specifically, `(x0 + r * Cos(theta), y0 + r * Sin(theta))`.